# Xamarin: weird layout during loading in collection

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, collectionview

In my xamarin collectionview, when I setup EmptyView, during loading items from my db online, collection empty view change position on the side of header. After content is loaded everything works perfectly. see attached screenshots. this happens ONLY on android devices, not on iOS

I’m using Xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2515

My code:

```
<CollectionView
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}"
    Margin="-2, 10, 0, 0"
    RemainingItemsThreshold="1"
    RemainingItemsThresholdReached="CollectionView_RemainingItemsThresholdReached"
    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem"
    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
    >
    <!-- ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem" è necessario per bug su ios. se c'è un solo elemento, questo si posiziona in centro e non a sinistra

    questo è un link per il bug: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6851 ma il fix è in un'altra pagina

    -->

    <CollectionView.Header>

        <StackLayout>
            <!--stack per immagine, nome, post, follower, following-->
            <StackLayout
                Orientation="Horizontal">

                 <!--foto + nome--> 
                <StackLayout
                Orientation="Vertical"
                Margin="10">

                 <!--immagine attuale--> 
                <Frame
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    HeightRequest="80"
                    WidthRequest="80"
                    HasShadow="False"
                    CornerRadius="40"
                    IsClippedToBounds="True"
                    Padding="0"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center">

                    <Image
                        x:Name="ImageProfile"
                        HeightRequest="80"
                        WidthRequest="80"
                        Aspect="Fill"
                        Source="{Binding ImgSource}"/>

                </Frame>

                <Label
                    Text="{Binding Name}"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    FontFamily="Helvetica Neue Medium"
                    FontSize="15"
                    TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=black, Dark=white}"/>


            </StackLayout>

                 <!--post, follower, following-->
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         Margin="10, 0, 10, 0"
                         >

            
                 <!--numero post--> 
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                         Spacing="3"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                         Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"
                         WidthRequest="70">

                <Label 
                       Style="{StaticResource GeneralFont}"
                       FontSize="11"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=black, Dark=white}"
                       IsVisible="{Binding IsPostsLoaded}"
                    Text="{Binding NumberOfPostsString}"/>

                <ActivityIndicator
                    x:Name="Activity_posts"
                    IsRunning="True"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsPostsLoaded, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}}"
                    WidthRequest="11"
                    HeightRequest="11"
                    Color="{AppThemeBinding Light=Black, Dark=White}">

                    <ActivityIndicator.Scale>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                    iOS="0.7"/>
                    </ActivityIndicator.Scale>


                </ActivityIndicator>




                <Label
                    Text="Posts"
                    TabIndex="0"
                    Style="{StaticResource GeneralFont}"
                    FontSize="11"
                    HeightRequest="20"
                    TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Black, Dark=White}"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>


            </StackLayout>

                 <!--numero follower--> 
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                         Spacing="3"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                         Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"
                         TabIndex="0"
                         WidthRequest="70">

                <Label 
                       Style="{StaticResource GeneralFont}"
                       FontSize="11"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=black, Dark=white}"
                       IsVisible="{Binding IsFollowLoaded}"
                    Text="{Binding NumberOfFollowerString}"/>

                <ActivityIndicator
                    x:Name="Activity_followers"
                    IsRunning="True"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsFollowLoaded, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}}"
                    WidthRequest="11"
                    HeightRequest="11"
                    Color="{AppThemeBinding Light=Black, Dark=White}">

                    <ActivityIndicator.Scale>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                    iOS="0.7"/>
                    </ActivityIndicator.Scale>


                </ActivityIndicator>




                <Label
                    Text="Followers"
                    Style="{StaticResource GeneralFont}"
                    FontSize="11"
                    HeightRequest="20"
                    TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Black, Dark=White}"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="FollowerFollowingClicked"/>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>


            </StackLayout>

                 <!--numero following--> 
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                         Grid.Row="0"
                         Spacing="3"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                         Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"
                         TabIndex="1"
                         WidthRequest="70">

                <Label 
                       Style="{StaticResource GeneralFont}"
                       FontSize="11"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=black, Dark=white}"
                       IsVisible="{Binding IsFollowLoaded}"
                    Text="{Binding NumberOfFollowingString}"/>

                <ActivityIndicator
                    x:Name="Activity_following"
                    IsRunning="True"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsFollowLoaded, Converter={StaticResource BooleanConverter}}"
                    WidthRequest="11"
                    HeightRequest="11"
                    Color="{AppThemeBinding Light=Black, Dark=White}">

                    <ActivityIndicator.Scale>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                    iOS="0.7"/>
                    </ActivityIndicator.Scale>


                </ActivityIndicator>




                <Label
                    Text="Following"
                    Style="{StaticResource GeneralFont}"
                    FontSize="11"
                    HeightRequest="20"
                    TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Black, Dark=White}"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="FollowerFollowingClicked"/>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>


            </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>

            <!--bottoni follow, chat, report--> 
            <Grid
            ColumnDefinitions="*, *, 50"
            Margin="10, 10, 10, 0">

            <!--<commonui:ButtonWithActivityIndicator
                x:Name="BtnFollow"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Text="{Binding BtnFollowText}"
                Clicked="FollowClicked"
                FontSize="13"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                CornerRadius="10"
                HeightRequest="35"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                TextColor="{Binding BtnFollowTextColor}"
                ButtonBackgroundColorHEX="{Binding BtnFollowBackgroundColorHEX}"
                ActivityIndicatorColor="{Binding BtnFollowActivityColor}"
               >

            </commonui:ButtonWithActivityIndicator>-->

            <Button
                Text="Chat"
                Clicked="ChatClicked"
                Margin="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Style="{StaticResource GeneralFont}"
                FontSize="13"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Black, Dark=White}"
                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#efefef, Dark=#262626}"
                CornerRadius="10"
                HeightRequest="35"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                    />

            <ImageButton
                Clicked="ReportClicked"
                Source="{AppThemeBinding Light=alertblack.png, Dark=alertwhite.png}"
                Margin="0"
                Grid.Column="2"
                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#efefef, Dark=#262626}"
                CornerRadius="10"
                HeightRequest="35"
                VerticalOptions="Center"/>


        </Grid>

            <BoxView HeightRequest="0.7"
                 Color="{AppThemeBinding Light=#e3e3e3, Dark=#8b8b8b}"
                 Grid.Row="7"
                 Margin="10, 10, 10, 10"/>


        </StackLayout>

    </CollectionView.Header>
    

    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Span="3"
            HorizontalItemSpacing="2"
            VerticalItemSpacing="2"
            />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>


            <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                DownsampleToViewSize="False"
                Source="{Binding ImgSource}"
                TabIndex="{Binding ID}"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Aspect="AspectFill"
                HeightRequest="{Binding WidthHeightImage}">

                <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ImageClicked"/>
                </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>

            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>


        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    <CollectionView.Footer>

        <StackLayout
            HeightRequest="80"
            IsVisible="{Binding IsLoadingMorePosts}">

            <ActivityIndicator
                IsRunning="True"
                WidthRequest="50"
                HeightRequest="50"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Color="{AppThemeBinding Light=Black, Dark=White}">

                <ActivityIndicator.Scale>
                    <OnPlatform
                        x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                        iOS="0.7"/>
                </ActivityIndicator.Scale>
            </ActivityIndicator>

        </StackLayout>
                    
    </CollectionView.Footer>

    <CollectionView.EmptyView>

            <Grid
                ColumnDefinitions="*, *, *"
                RowDefinitions="{Binding RowDefinitions}"
                ColumnSpacing="1"
                RowSpacing="1"
                IsVisible="{Binding IsFirstLoading}">

            <commonui:SkeletonView 
                CornerRadius="5"
                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#efefef, Dark=#262626}"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0">
            </commonui:SkeletonView>

            <commonui:SkeletonView 
                CornerRadius="5"
                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#efefef, Dark=#262626}"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="0">
            </commonui:SkeletonView>

            <commonui:SkeletonView 
                Grid.Column="2"
                CornerRadius="5"
                Grid.Row="0"
                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#efefef, Dark=#262626}">
            </commonui:SkeletonView>

                <commonui:SkeletonView 
                CornerRadius="5"
                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#efefef, Dark=#262626}"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1">
            </commonui:SkeletonView>

            <commonui:SkeletonView 
                CornerRadius="5"
                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#efefef, Dark=#262626}"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1">
            </commonui:SkeletonView>

            <commonui:SkeletonView 
                Grid.Column="2"
                CornerRadius="5"
                Grid.Row="1"
                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#efefef, Dark=#262626}">
            </commonui:SkeletonView>

                <commonui:SkeletonView 
                CornerRadius="5"
                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#efefef, Dark=#262626}"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="2">
            </commonui:SkeletonView>

            <commonui:SkeletonView 
                CornerRadius="5"
                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#efefef, Dark=#262626}"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="2">
            </commonui:SkeletonView>

            <commonui:SkeletonView 
                Grid.Column="2"
                CornerRadius="5"
                Grid.Row="2"
                BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#efefef, Dark=#262626}">
            </commonui:SkeletonView>

        </Grid>

            <!--<Label
                Text="Nessun post"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                FontFamily="Helvetica Neue Medium"
                FontSize="20"
                TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=black, Dark=white}"
                IsVisible="{Binding UserHasNoPost}"
                Margin="0, 20, 0, 0"/>-->


    </CollectionView.EmptyView>

</CollectionView>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add to question all xaml *before* the xaml you show (earlier in xaml file). The problem is that the collectionview, or its parent, isn't automatically "filling the width of the screen", until it sees the contents. Adding `HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"` or `HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"` might fix. But don't know where to add that, until see the missing xaml.

Comment: tried but it seems solutions doesn't work. see my edited post for complete xaml

Comment: Also need to show the xaml of the **parent** element. Maybe `<StackLayout ... <CollectionView>` or similar. (Where I have `...`, put in the actual xaml.)